# Wrong jinja2 blueprint route

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm developing a Python-Flask application and I'm trying to implement a simple **search** function:

**home/views.py**

```
from . import home_blueprint
################################# SEARCH #################################


@home_blueprint.route("/search")
@login_required
def search():
    results = Politic.query.whoosh_search(request.args.get('query')).all()
    #results = Politic.query.whoosh_search(query).all()
    for p in results:
        print p.publicName
    print results
    return render_template('search_results.html',
                           results=results)
```

Pretty simple and I got it working before I included blueprint on my project. When I'm calling this function on my view, I don't get anything.

**updated!** my **base.html** file:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{url_for('home.search')}}">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="query">Poltician</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" id="query">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          </form>
```

Since url_for looks for a function I passed my home_blueprint and the function I want to call (search).

Is there any reason why I'm not getting the into the **search** function? Am I doing something wrong in my **.html** file?

Best regards

**EDIT:**(**init**.py)

```
#################
#### imports ####
#################

################
#### config ####
################
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)

from project.models import db, User, Politic, Organization
import datetime
from forms import SearchForm
import os
from flask_login import LoginManager, \
                               current_user





print(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['WHOOSH_BASE'] = 'whoosh'
db.init_app(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "users.login"


from project.users.views import users_blueprint
#from project.home.views import home_blueprint
from project.home import home_blueprint
from project.politicians.views import politicians_blueprint
from project.organizations.views import organizations_blueprint
from project.proposals.views import proposals_blueprint
from project.flag.views import flag_blueprint
# register our blueprints
app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(politicians_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(organizations_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(proposals_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(flag_blueprint)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = current_user
    if g.user.is_authenticated:
        g.user.last_seen = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.add(g.user)
        db.session.commit()
        g.search_form = SearchForm()


@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(email):
    """Given *user_id*, return the associated User object.

    :param unicode user_id: user_id (email) user to retrieve
    """
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
```

**EDIT** My project tree:

[image]

I did the changes metmirr suggested and now my project structure is this:
**project/home/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

home_blueprint = Blueprint(
    'home', __name__,
    template_folder='templates'
)

from . import views
```

**URL** when I search:

> http://localhost:5000/home?query=new

**when it should be:**

> http://localhost:5000/search?query=new

Still, it doesn't get into the search function.
I got no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is great! Thanks.

Comment: What URL is in the rendered HTML?

Comment: What output do you get? Did you try to debug?

Comment: nothing happens, it stays in my /home route and don't get to search even tho the `g.search_form.validate_on_submit()` is returning True. 
I need it to get to my search fuction which calls a redirect to **search_results.html**

Comment: What do you mean @dirn

Comment: You've told us what you want to happen, but not what is happening. What URL is returned by `url_for`? Which endpoint is being called? Are you getting an errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the python interpreter in your project, (Make sure to activate your virtual env if you're using one) you can check the registered endpoints on the app and to which functions they point.

```
>>> import app
>>> app = app.create_app()
>>> app.url_map
Map([<Rule '/search' (OPTIONS, POST) -> **folder_where_your_search_views_are_located**.search>,
     <Rule '/search_results/<query>' (OPTIONS, GET) -> **folder_where_your_search_views_are_located**.search_results>])
```

Comment: `<Rule '/search' (POST, OPTIONS) -> home.search>,` 
Exactly what I got

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your problem. Probably you are creating `Blueprint` and `Flask` application in same place. Well the Blueprints are similar to a applications and flask has blueprints so you can have large application structure. I will show you two example first one doesnt work, other does:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
app.register_blueprint(main)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello Flask"
```

---

```
app/
   app.py
   main/
      __init__.py
      views.py
      forms

#app/app.py

from flask import Flask

from main import main as main_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

#main/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

# importing this module causes the routes to be associated with the blueprint
from . import views, forms

#main/views.py
from . import main

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello Flask"
```

So now when you write `action="{{url_for('main.index')}}"` will work fine.

Comment: If I do that, I get a : `BuildError: ('home_blueprint.search', {}, None)`

Comment: did you register `home_blueprint`

Comment: Yes, it is registered. It is really weird why this happens, whats the other 2 arguments?

Comment: `home_blueprint` is just the name of a variable. The blueprint name is whatever is passed to `Blueprint` in `home_blueprint = Blueprint(...)`. I'm assuming that's `'home'`.

Comment: Exactly, **home** is my blueprint name , so I'm assuming that the correct way to call a function inside my home_blueprint is `url_for('home.search')` . Am I right?

Comment: No, you have to use the name of your file where the search endpoint is located. So how's the file named in which your search views reside?

Comment: root/project/home/views.py/search. That is the path of my search function, @StijnDiependaele

Comment: @metmirr I added my `__init__.py` It seems that it is as you suggested, right?

Comment: If you are going to use blueprints  then follow my app structure

Comment: @Perseverance you are register blueprint as `app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)` and your search route is `@home_blueprint.route('/search')` so your action must be `action="{{url_for('home_blueprint.search')}}"`. You have to use instance name on your route not the actual name of blueprint `blueprint_instance = Blueprint('blueprint_name', __name__)`